# Codeigniter set value in database error

Tags: database, codeigniter, insert, set

id
ans1_r
ans2_r
ans3_r
ans4_r
ans5_r
ans6_r

I have these fields in **anketemale**  table. All fields are integers.

**`$answer` is the column name. `$id` is the id of chosen row.**
So I want to make +1 in specific row and just one of the ans fields. I wrote this code:

```
function upisi_malu($id,$answer)
    {
        $anketadb = $this->load->database('anketa',TRUE);

    $anketadb->select($answer);
    $anketadb->where('id', $id); 
    $q = $anketadb->get('anketemale');

    foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
    $ans = $row->$answer + 1;
    }
    echo $answer; //just to know I echo them, and values are right
    echo $ans;
    echo $id;
    $anketadb->set($answer, $ans); 
    $anketadb->where('id', $id); 
    $anketadb->insert('anketemale'); 
}
```

Why does this code write every change in new row? I just want to change row what already exist.

Comment: Because you're running an insert query and your database obviously doesn't have id set as a unique key.

Comment: Id is set on auto increment, and in every row it is make a new row with one bigger id, so I think is it is not about that.

Comment: Auto increment and setting it as a key are not the same thing. Look at your table in phpMyAdmin in structure, look at the bottom and see if any indexes are set I am guessing no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($q->result() as $row)
{
    $ans = $row->$answer + 1;
    $anketadb->set($answer, $ans); 
    $anketadb->where('id', $id); 
    $anketadb->update('anketemale');
}
```

This is the best guess I can come up with based on your information. You are using `insert` instead of `update` in your example. `insert` will always make a new row... `update` will only update ones that exist if the `where` matches.